# Retrieving data to Telegram bot with Python Script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am new to python programming and I need some help with this problem. I have two python scripts and here is the first one.

```html
import requests


def get_prices():
    name = "SeedifyFund"

    crypto_data = requests.get("https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens").json()["data"]

    data = None
    for i in crypto_data:
        current = crypto_data[i]

        if current['name'] == name:
          data = {
              "tokenname": current["name"],
              "symbol": current["symbol"],
              "priceUSD": current["price"],
              "priceBNB": current["price_BNB"],
          }

    return data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(get_prices())
```

The code above outputs the following: {'tokenname': 'SeedifyFund', 'symbol': 'SFUND', 'priceUSD': '2.663882711079554275551364745705683', 'priceBNB': '0.007149269615227117843007204049908718'}
[Finished in 1.5s]

I want it to use the data that is being collected above and print it in a telegram bot when the user types /price. Here is the main script:

```html
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
from tracker import get_prices


telegram_bot_token = "Telegram Bot API"

updater = Updater(token=telegram_bot_token, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher


def price(update, context):
    chat_id = update.effective_chat.id
    message = ""

    crypto_data = get_prices()
    for i in crypto_data:
        name = crypto_data["tokenname"]
        symbol = crypto_data["symbol"]
        usdprice = crypto_data["priceUSD"]
        bnbprice = crypto_data["priceBNB"]
        message = f"Name: ${name}\nSymbol: {symbol}\nPrice: ${usdprice}\nUSD: {bnbprice} BNB\n\n"

    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)


dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("price", price))
updater.start_polling()
```

It gives me no error but it prints four times. Here is the output when the user type /price:

```html
Name: $SeedifyFund
Symbol: SFUND
Price: $2.643444449416822156922888549443618
USD: 0.007129853620305430644161283699928471 BNB

Name: $SeedifyFund
Symbol: SFUND
Price: $2.643444449416822156922888549443618
USD: 0.007129853620305430644161283699928471 BNB

Name: $SeedifyFund
Symbol: SFUND
Price: $2.643444449416822156922888549443618
USD: 0.007129853620305430644161283699928471 BNB

Name: $SeedifyFund
Symbol: SFUND
Price: $2.643444449416822156922888549443618
USD: 0.007129853620305430644161283699928471 BNB
```

Could someone help me out? I want to achieve this output. Will you please tell me what I've done wrong? Thank you.

```html
Name: $SeedifyFund
Symbol: SFUND
Price: $2.64
USD: 0.007 BNB
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is what you have here:

```
crypto_data = get_prices()
    for i in crypto_data:
        name = crypto_data["tokenname"]
        symbol = crypto_data["symbol"]
        usdprice = crypto_data["priceUSD"]
        bnbprice = crypto_data["priceBNB"]
        message = f"Name: ${name}\nSymbol: {symbol}\nPrice: ${usdprice}\nUSD: {bnbprice} BNB\n\n"
```

crypto_data is a dictionnary. When you write "for i in crypto_data", you iterate over the four values of the dictionnary, printing the same thing four times.

Try:

```
crypto_data = get_prices()
name = crypto_data["tokenname"]
symbol = crypto_data["symbol"]
usdprice = crypto_data["priceUSD"]
bnbprice = crypto_data["priceBNB"]
message = f"Name: ${name}\nSymbol: {symbol}\nPrice: ${usdprice}\nUSD: {bnbprice} BNB\n\n"
```

Also if you want a precision of 3 when printing change this line

```
message = f"Name: ${name}\nSymbol: {symbol}\nPrice: ${usdprice}\nUSD: {bnbprice} BNB\n\n"
```

to

```
message = f"Name: ${name}\nSymbol: {symbol}\nPrice: ${usdprice:.3f}\nUSD: {bnbprice:.3f} BNB\n\n"
```